# Outlook Interop Exception (E_NOINTERFACE) in Release mode

Tags: c#, com, outlook, office-interop, com-interop

I'm trying to make a program that would open a new Outlook 2013 message.
I've referenced Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook 15.0.0.0.

When running in Debug mode everything works fine but crashes in Release mode with Exception:

> Unable to cast COM object of type
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass' to interface type
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Application'. This operation failed
>   because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface
>   with IID '{00063001-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the
>   following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

Code:

```
 var _Outlook = new MSOutlook.Application();
 var _MailItem = _Outlook.CreateItem(MSOutlook.OlItemType.olMailItem) as MSOutlook.MailItem;
 var _Recip = _MailItem.Recipients.Add("xxx@yyy.com");
 Recip.Type = (int)MSOutlook.OlMailRecipientType.olTo;

 _MailItem.Recipients.ResolveAll();
 _MailItem.Subject = "xxx";

 _MailItem.Display(false);
```

where MSOutlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook namespace.

I am using .NET Framework 4.5 and Outlook 2013.

How can Release mode affect this? Strangely Debug mode works fine..

I'll be grateful for any ideas how to solve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by enabling "Prefer 32-bit" in Project Settings -> Build -> General.

It's probably also possible to resolve the recipients object at runtime via dynamic:

```
var _Recip = ((dynamic)_MailItem.Recipients).Add("xxx@yyy.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to explicitly declare the _Outlook variable type:

```
MSOutlook.Application _Outlook = new MSOutlook.Application();
```

Comment: Same exception as before.. Seems like it has something to do with 64 bit because "Prefer 32-bit" solved the problem - http://i.imgur.com/yQXmDua.png

Answer (score -2):

Where and when do you try to run the code? Did you have a chance to check out the list of running processes? Does it contain the OUtlook.exe entry?

Try to use Reflection to create a new Application instance:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Outlook.Application"));
```